# Echoing file name from include page

Tags: php, filenames

I don't think my question really gives enough insight.

Basically. I'm looking to echo the file name, even though this function will be called from my header.php file.

Here's some code to help you understand:

**index.php**

```
      <?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en-gb">
        <?php getHeader(); // Get header ?>
      </html>
```

**functions.php**

```
    <?php

    // Get header
    function getHeader(){
        include 'header.php';
    }

    // Get filename
    function pageTitle(){
        echo ucfirst(basename(__FILE__, '.php'));
    }

    ?>
```

And finally...

**header.php**

```
<head>
    <title><?php pageTitle(); ?></title>
</head>
```

But, here's the problem, because the code `echo ucfirst(basename(__FILE__, '.php'));` is in my `functions.php` file, it just echo's the functions.php filename.

Any ideas on how to make it echo 'index', rather than 'functions'?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could pass `__FILE__` as an argument..

Comment: Would you be able to demonstrate, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__FILE__` will give you the file system path of the **current *.php* page**, not the one where you've included it. Simply pass the file name to `getHeader()` function, like this:

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<?php getHeader(ucfirst(basename(__FILE__, '.php'))); ?>
</html>
```

Subsequently change your *functions.php* and *header.php* file in the following way,

**functions.php**

```
<?php
    // Get header
    function getHeader($file){
        include 'header.php';
    }

    // Get filename
    function pageTitle($file){
        echo $file;
    }
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<head>
    <title><?php pageTitle($file); ?></title>
</head>
```

Comment: This code displays a 500 error. Please fix your code. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobPunton It's working fine on my end. Please check your server's error log.

Comment: You are a beauty. I missed the `($file)` within the pageTitle. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a variable in *index.php* that contains the file name and then use the same variable to return filename like:

**index.php**

```
<?php $includerFile = __FILE__; ?>
<?php include 'functions.php'; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<?php getHeader(); // Get header ?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

    // Get header
    function getHeader(){
        include 'header.php';
    }

    // Get filename
    function pageTitle(){
        echo ucfirst(basename($includerFile, '.php'));
    }

?>
```

To make it more systematic you can do it this way:

This is actually just a special case of what PHP templating engines do. Consider having this function:

**index.php**

```
<?php

    function ScopedInclude($file, $params = array())
    {
        extract($params);
        include $file;
    } 

    ScopedInclude('functions.php', array('includerFile' => __FILE__));

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">
<?php getHeader(); // Get header ?>
```

Comment: @SnehaMaheshwari, I've edited your answer and fixed few formatting issues. Hope that's okay.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I saw. Thanks for that.

Comment: @JacobPunton I have two files in my folder in 1.php I wrote
<?php
$x = 10;
$y = include("2.php");
echo $y;
?>
In 2.php I wrote:
<?php
return $x;
?>

And the output is 10. Hence its working. If you can show the the code you edited, I can help.